# Behavior of getCString and withCString on different architectures

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm trying to implement AES 128 in Swift and recently ran into a problem with writing a Swift String to a `CChar` array:

```
let testString = "myTestString"

var keyPtr = [CChar](count: kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
bzero(&keyPtr, strideof(keyPtr.dynamicType))
testString.getCString(&keyPtr, maxLength: strideof(keyPtr.dynamicType), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(keyPtr)
```

On 32-bit devices (iPad 2, iPad 4) this logs:

```
[109, 121, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

while on 64-bit devices (iPhone 6, Macbook Pro i7) this logs:

```
[109, 121, 84, 101, 115, 116, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The 64-bit case is the correct result, while the 32-bit result does not.

I run into the same issue with `withCString` as well:

```
testString.withCString({
    print($0)
})
```

On a 32-bit device this logs `0x7a992094` while a 64-bit device logs `0x00007f853c123760`.

How can I make the result of `getCString` or `withCString` the same across all architectures?  Is this an issue with the size of `CChar` or arrays on the different architectures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad point is this: `strideof(keyPtr.dynamicType)`
It is the same as `strideof(Array<CChar>)`, and its value is 4 in 32-bit, 8 in 64-bit.

You need to modify your code like this:

```
bzero(&keyPtr, keyPtr.count) //<-this is not needed, as you are specifying `0` for `repeatedValue`.
testString.getCString(&keyPtr, maxLength: keyPtr.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Yep, pretty sure this is it.  And `withCString` threw me off because I was printing the memory location, not the contents at that memory.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, since you asked about `withCString()`:

That method calls creates a temporary C String representation
(i.e. a NUL-terminated sequence of `CChar`) of
the Swift string, and calls the closure with `$0` set to the address
(of the first character) in that string. So `$0` is a *pointer*
and therefore 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the platform.

And you can copy that C string to the given array with:

```
testString.withCString { strlcpy(&keyPtr, $0, keyPtr.count) }
```

Comment: Is this why you recommend `withCString` over `getCString`?  I remember that from [one of your answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135430/73433) on Code Review.

Comment: @JAL: That was about cStringUsingEncoding, not getCString, but any of these methods is fine.